# How to make the UI dispatcher resume the continuation immediately

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I've been heavily using coroutines in my Android project. For example, I use them to hand off blocking calls and CPU-intensive tasks to a threadpool. This is where `launch(UI)` works perfectly: it ensures the continuation resumes on the UI thread.

I'm also using coroutines for stuff like awaiting for the first `onDraw` call, resuming the animation loop with a `postOnAnimate()`, etc. In these cases the UI context falls short of what I need because it resumes the continuation asynchronously, by submitting an item to the event loop, even though `cont.resume()` is called on the UI thread.

This has become particularly bad in the case where I await the first `onDraw` call on an `ImageView`: I have to reposition the image based on the now-known view dimensions. However, since the coroutine resumes asynchronously, `onDraw()` completes, then a few more run, and only then does my coroutine resume. The user experiences flicker because the improperly positioned image briefly appears.

Is there an option to force the UI dispatcher to resume immediately whenever `cont.resume()` is called on the UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can study the implementation of `awaitFrame` in Adroind context [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-android/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/android/HandlerContext.kt#L72) and use a similar technique. In particular, when coroutine is suspended with `suspendCancellableCoroutine` function then you can ask to resume it *undispatched* if you already run in the context of this dispatcher by usin `resumeUndispatched` function in the resulting `CancellableContinuation`. You have have to supply a reference to the corresponding dispatcher as a "proof" and use the following code pattern:

```
with(continuation) { dispatcher.resumeUndispatched(value) }
```

This approach is safe in the sense that if the coroutine that you are resuming is using a different dispatcher, then it will still be dispatched to the appropriate dispatcher. Dispatching is suppressed only if it is running in the dispatcher that you've specified.

Comment: `awaitFrame` was exactly the code I studied, but I was thrown off by the docs on `resumeUndispatched`: "This function is designed to be used only by the CoroutineDispatcher implementations themselves. **It should not be used in general code.**" (original emphasis). Is in considered private/unstable API?

Comment: The idea was that only dispatcher implementation would need to use it, but it does seem that Android opens a can of worms where there maybe many, many points where it can be usefully used. I wonder if there can be a different solution to this problem. 

We had a similar problem with `launch` where, for example, inside `onClick` event listener you might want to `launch` a new UI coroutine but there is no point is scheduling it via dispatcher, so `CoroutineStart.UNDISPATCHED` was added.

Comment: Yes, that covered the same issue from the other end. In my project I actually define a `start` function that hardcodes `launch(UI, start = UNDISPATCHED)`. What would be the downside of `resumeUndispatched` behavior being the default?

Comment: If you launch undispatched, then the outer code will not run until the code you've launched suspends. It might be Ok if UI context which is multithreaded and it is assumed that you don't have any long running code, but since our default context is multithreaded it does not have much sense of resume undispatched. Morever, you use more OS stack undispatched and may end up with stack overflow. Being dispatched is just a safer default. Also read this: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/-coroutine-dispatcher/is-dispatch-needed.html

Comment: I have studied this reasoning and discussed it with my colleague. Giving the user the `CoroutineStart` option is all that's needed; however i was wondering for the opposite end: `cont.resume()`. I guess the same reasoning applies there, too. Maybe it would be possible to provide the same configurability in the `launch` invocation?

Comment: Actually, this decision is specific to the resumption point and not to the entire coroutine, so configuring it at `launch` time doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: I implemented it and works as expected. I think my use case is well-served with this approach, except the syntax looks weird: `onDrawCont?.apply { onDrawCont = null; UI.resumeUndispatched(Unit) }` It looks like the dispatecher resumes itself, without a continuation.

Comment: If you have ideas on better syntax that serves your use-case, then please open issue at https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues